# Problems with using django-crontab in Heroku (Django project)

Tags: python, django, heroku, cron, django-cron

it is impossible for me to run cron jobs using django-crontab in heroku. Cron job seems to run fine for me locally but failed in heroku server. Following this tutorial and it works fine without heroku (https://hprog99.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/how-to-setup-django-cron-jobs/)

Let me share with you my codes:

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_crontab',
     # more codes
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('0 0 * * *', 'cinemas.cron.hello')
]
```

cinemas/cron.py

```
def hello():
    print('This job is run every day at 12am.')
```

finally i ran this:

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

However, heroku produce this error message:

```
/var/spool/cron: No such file or directory
```

seems like there is no cron directory in heroku? Anyway around this if I were to use django-crontab in heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Correct - the Heroku dynos do not have many of the "normal" utilities you'd expect to find on a Linux machine (the dyno is a container, not a full machine).It looks like `django-crontab` actually tries to interact with the native `crontab` utility.